# Formula needed for column and row dependency

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, transpose, array-formulas

Tried several times with `Query` formula, but failed so far.

I have a simple source that looks like this, columns of date, product and quantity.

[image: Log]

On another sheet I have a table that has the products on the Y-axis and the years on the X-axis. Both axis I want to expand over time with the products and years available in the source and their respective sum of quantities in the grid.

[image: Summary]

Existing formulas are:

To put out the years in row 1.

```
=transpose(ArrayFormula(SORT(UNIQUE(YEAR(FILTER(Log!A2:A,ISNUMBER(Log!A2:A)))),0,false)))
```

To put out the products in column A.

```
=query(Products!A2:A,"select A where A is not null order by A")
```

What formula I have to put in B2 to find all the quantities from the source table matching their respective year of date and their product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=arrayformula(query({year(Log!A2:A),Log!C2:D},"Select Col2,sum(Col3) Where Col2<>'' group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
```

- *Adjust the ranges in the formulas as per your sheet*

Comment: Works nicely out of the box already. 

Let's say I want to do the same for months instead of years. How do I put out all 12 months, not just the existing in Log!A2:A and how do I replace the resulting integer value with its month (January, February, ...)?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Sure @rockinfreakshow. Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11g2xbbNKtfjK-kuS9YT4UQcFAvWAjekavPFNXuIvSEg/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: There's no input data added within the sheet

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I added the input data.

Comment: Formula added to the test sheet

Comment: Wow, that's a complex one.  Is it possible to filter for Activity=Harvest only? If Log has Plant values, those should be overriden.

Comment: Thx again for your comprehensive support! 